# Is Any built-in control available in DevExpress or Microsoft which contains the Alignment buttons like Microsoft excel having?

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I need to add the control like Microsoft excel having to change the Alignment. Attached the image the below to show what i need to know whether the Devexpress or Microsoft already having any control related to this ???

[image]

Please share your suggestion on this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You can build your own by using Horizontal Alignment Left, Center, Right on any control

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress have tons of controls and it seems you are talking about the MS Word text editing. If so, and you are a first-time user of [DXRichEditControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8651), you can refer to the following tutorial that describes how to start with it and create all the UI buttons related to the DXRichEdit' actions:

- [Provide a Ribbon UI for a Rich Text Editor](http://Provide%20a%20Ribbon%20UI%20for%20a%20Rich%20Text%20Editor)
- [Provide a Bar UI for a Rich Text Editor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8847)